# Ul show only first 10 li at start and with next clicked show 10-20 then 20-30

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want page to show only first 10 `li` in a specific `ul`. in css: 
    ul#asd li { 
        display:none 
    }
    ul#asd li:nth-child(2) { 
        display:block 
    }
    ul#asd li:nth-child(3) { 
        display:block 
    }

is enough only for this matter. but i want it to show the next 10 in order when the Next button clicked. 
So show first 10 at start, when Next button clicked show 10 to 20 th `<li>` s and it goes like that. If the function can be commanded by an input field to enter page numbers and 2 buttons 'next' 'previous' it will be perfect solution. I wonder if there is a code to force the page to load only visible content.  Thank you for your answers.

```
 <ul id="asd">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
 </ul>

 <button id="prev" onSubmit="">prev</button>
 <input id="page" onSubmit="" />
 <button id="more" onSubmit="">next</button>
 </div>

 <script>
 function showPage(page) {
 var listItems = $("#asd li").toArray();
 var start = (10 * page) - 10; // this is if you use page 1
 // var start = (10 * page) // this is if you use page 0
 var showListItems = listItems.splice(start, 10);

 $(listItems).hide();
 $(showListItems).show();
 }</script>
```

Now the question is that I still need to use CSS, to do the formatting, so I can't call the function.

I also found http://jsfiddle.net/uXn2p/1/  but it was not useful for me; it keeps going after last page reached.

Comment: Would be nice to see your approach…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to splice the list items:

```
function showPage(page) {
    var listItems = $("#asd li").toArray();
    var start = (10 * page) - 10; // this is if you use page 1
    // var start = (10 * page) // this is if you use page 0
    var showListItems = listItems.splice(start, 10);

    $(listItems).hide();
    $(showListItems).show();
}
```

If you are tracking the current page number, then you can use your next button to increment the page, and then call showPage(page). You can also use this for previous, or jumping to a previous page.

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dpD56/1/). This isn't complete, as you will need to add logic for disabling the buttons when there is no next/prev, as well as logic to handle a jump to a page that does not exist.

Comment: i edited my post. cant really get it work. i think im calling function wrong. and for the hiding li items do i need to use css still ?

Comment: @user3321234 You aren't calling the function at all, from your edit. You need to add a `type="button"` to your buttons. You also need an onclick method for the buttons. I'll update my answer.